# How to calculate the second-type curve integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to calculate the second type curve integral $I=\int_{L} \frac{4 x-y}{4 x^{2}+y^{2}} d x+\frac{x+y}{4 x^{2}+y^{2}} d y$, where $L$ is the curve $x^{2}+y^{2}=2$ (the direction is the counter clockwise direction of curve $x^{2}+y^{2}=2$).

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 == 2, {x, y}];
f[x_] := Sqrt[2 - x^2]
Integrate[(4 x - y)/(4 x^2 + y^2)*-D[f[x], x]/Sqrt[
   1 + D[f[x], x]^2] + (x + y)/(4 x^2 + y^2)*1/Sqrt[
   1 + D[f[x], x]^2], {x, y} ∈ reg]
```

I use the above code to calculate, but I can't get the correct result (the answer is $\pi$).

What can I do to solve this curve integral correctly?

**Supplementary information**

Maple's calculation result is also $\pi$:

[image]

Comment: You're mixing up the scalar integral and the vector integral. The true result  is zero. Apply Green's theorem: let `p = (4 x - y)/(4 x^2 + y^2); q = (x + y)/(4 x^2 + y^2);` then by Green's theorem we have $$\int_{C} P d x+Q d y=\iint_{D}\left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right) dA$$. Where dA means integrate over the disk of radius `Sqrt[2]` - giving us the result: `Integrate[(D[q, x] - D[p, y]), {x, y} \[Element] 
  Disk[{0, 0}, Sqrt[2]]]` of zero

Comment: If you want the vector line integral (flux) then do `p = (4 x - y)/(4 x^2 + y^2);
q = (x + y)/(4 x^2 + y^2);
transformation = {x -> Sqrt[2] Cos[t], y -> Sqrt[2] Sin[t]};
Tp = p /. transformation;
Tq = q /. transformation;
curve[t_] := {Sqrt[2] Cos[t], Sqrt[2] Sin[t]}` and calculate `Integrate[{Tp, Tq}.D[curve[t], t], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]` which gives Maple's result of Pi

Comment: @flinty Because `{0,0}` is a singular point, it will lead to discontinuous partial derivatives of functions `P` and `Q`, so green's theorem can not be directly used here.

Comment: Right - good point. But I think you can get around that by using a contour that avoids it but nets out the same. See here https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/GreensTheorem.aspx

Answer (score 2):

We can integrate over the region without transforming to an area or changing to a polar variable ($\theta$, that is).

`Integrate[1,{x,y} ∈ reg]` gives the circumference, so we know the integration over the region is wrt path length, $ds$.  Now, $dx = d(R\,cos\theta) = -R\,sin\theta\,d\theta = -(y/R) ds$ along the path.  This is *not* the same transformation that would be used to integrate wrt $\theta$, by a factor of $r$.  Similarly for $dy$.

```
p = (4 x - y)/(4 x^2 + y^2);
q = (x + y)/(4 x^2 + y^2);
xform = {-y/r, x/r} /. r -> Sqrt[2];

Integrate[{p, q}.xform, {x, y} reg]    (*  π  *)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CurveIntegrateFor2nd[{u_, v_}, curve_, {x_, y_}, reg_, opt___] := 
 Block[{x1, y1, cur = curve /. x1_ == y1_ :> x1 - y1}, 
  Integrate[{u, v}.({-1, 1}*Normalize[D[cur, {{y, x}}]]) /. 
    Abs -> RealAbs, {x, y} ∈ reg, opt]]

With[{curve2 = x^2 + y^2 == 2}, 
 CurveIntegrateFor2nd[{(4 x - y)/(4 x^2 + y^2), (x + y)/(
   4 x^2 + y^2)}, curve2, {x, y}, ImplicitRegion[curve2, {x, y}]]]
```